# Zoom into character upon collision

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

When a character collides with an object in my game, there is a slow motion effect. That's coool, but how would I zoom into a sprite when it collides with another object?

Here is my code currently...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float slowness = 2f;

    public int index;

    private AudioSource hitSource;

    public Vector3[] Target;
    public Camera Cam;
    public float Speed = 0.012f;


    public void Start()
    {
        Cam = Camera.main;

    }

    public void EndGame()
    {
        Application.targetFrameRate = 300;

        StartCoroutine(RestartLevel());

        hitSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    }


    IEnumerator RestartLevel()
    {
        Cam.orthographicSize = Mathf.Lerp(Cam.orthographicSize, 3, Speed);
        Cam.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(Cam.transform.position, Target[1], Speed);

        Time.timeScale = 1f / slowness;

        Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.fixedDeltaTime / slowness;

           yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f/slowness);

        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.fixedDeltaTime * slowness;



        SceneManager.LoadScene(2);

    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'interpolate' (commonly shortened to 'interp') your 'camera position' towards the object.

**Edit**

You have correctly identified a collision response event.

However, the name of your class seems to suggest that you are attempting to deal with this collision outside of either the player or the sprite that you have collided with.

1. Step 1 is to put your collision response inside your player object.
   Your player should be responsible for handling its own collision -
   your game manager should **not** be responsible for handling
   something else's collision, make sense?
2. You need to interp your camera position towards the sprite if it has been collided with

To do this:

1. Calculate the *vector* from your camera to the collided sprite -
   `Vector = CollidedSprite.WorldLocation - Camera.WorldLocation`
2. Each *frame* (tick), adjust the camera's position *a fraction* of this *vector* e.g. `Camera.WorldLocation += Vector / 10`
3. It stands to reason that after 10 frames in this example, the camera will have travelled 10 1/10ths of the way towards the sprite's location. You likely don't want it to travel all of the way, so you'll probably want to move the camera by 50-75% of the calculated vector. Make sure that when you have travelled the required amount, you halt whatever repeated process is causing this camera position change.

Comment: @UsmaanMahmood If you want help adding features to your code, then you should include that code in your question.

Comment: Please refer above.

Comment: "interpolate" is commonly shortened to "lerp", not "interp".

Comment: @Evorlor 'Lerp' is a shortening of 'Linear Interpolation'. 'Interp' is a shortening of 'Interpolate' This is clearly a beginner question, so regardless of which method they use, Linear or otherwise, they will encounter shortenings to 'Interp'. If you require evidence of Interp being a common shortening, please look at various Unreal Blueprint nodes using the term Interp.

Comment: @UsmaanMahmood I'll get back to your query tomorrow when I have the time

Comment: @UsmaanMahmood I have edited my question to attempt to answer your new query

Comment: Thanks for that! How would that look like in the code though? Such as how do I define collidersprite, vector and worldlocation and do I make a private oncollision?

Comment: @UsmaanMahmood Those are very different and large questions that need to be asked and answered away from this post.

Comment: I have added this where it does zoom in but it doesn't track the player and it doesn't smoothly pan in as it just snaps into it :/.

Comment: @UsmaanMahmood You need to lower the interp speed (increase the time it takes to change to the desired location. I don't know what you mean by track the player as well as zoom in on the collided sprite?

Comment: I mean that if the sprite is in the middle of the screen then it zooms into the centre, but if the sprite is too far to the left or right then the camera zooms in the centre still.